# Very old Coleman gas wall mounted furnace

Tags: heating

The control dial (Lo, 1, 2, 3, etc.) no longer seems to be working.  Furnace is either up all the way or I can turn it off.  No medium range.  Pilot stays lit.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Diane

Comment: Would have it checked by a gas technician.  Might be only the dial or the gas valve it controls.  Possible if the pilot light goes out, the gas valve will not turn off.